# PHP MYSQL JQUERY Feedback/Notification System for Server Events

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I need to build a notification system for a website that gets traffic from at least 5,000 users at the moment.

The users win points performing certain activities. This activity gets recorded to a database table.

The problem is, it's not always an AJAX call to the server that does it. One of the items is an iFrame photo upload. Plus, not every user is enrolled in points, so I want to avoid building code that looks for these things when updates occur, so I don't have to write alternative code for users not enrolled. Lots of these things are normal actions that any user would do, enrolled or not.

I want to show a div on the page describing the reward the user just did. It's similar to the way XBOX Gamerscore points are shown when awarded.

My best idea thus far is to run an AJAX call to the server at an interval looking for non-alerted items. But I want to keep it light, like once every 10-15 seconds.

Any other solutions for this? I'm running this off a shared hosting environment, so I won't have the ability to do crazy things with the server nor be able to do long polling.

Thanks!
Clint

Comment: You're on the right track with an interval AJAX call, I think.  One thing to keep in mind, though, is when a new call is made, that it cancels all previous calls.  Any failure between the browser and the server can cause a call to hang for a time, or indefinitely, so you'll want to make sure responses don't stack on each other.

Comment: Good point. I'll have to set a flag variable that will prevent it from checking again until it's been firmly set to "finished". :)

Comment: That will prevent multiple simultaneous calls, but if the server fails to respond, the page will quit requesting. I have a similar application, and I find it more reliable to cancel a request in progress and start a new one, rather than wait for the previous one to finish. It's a little more JavaScript, and a little more server load, but if reliability is important, it's worth it.